# Como montar uma RegEx para identificar o estado das interfaces

Tags: regex, linux

Usando o comando `ip link show` no terminal eu obtenho o seguintes texto:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:01:1e:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:54:4b:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Com essa regex: `(?<=eth0:)(.*)` eu já consigo pegar toda a linha do eth0 e ignora-lo, mas eu não consegui fazer com que ele pare na palavra `"state"`, e fazer ignorar tudo entre `"eth0:"` e `"state"` e pegar somente o estado UP/DOWN/UNKNOWN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisa ser com regex? Você pode usar [`awk`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) para pegar somente o campo correspondente ao status, e passar o nome da interface como parâmetro do comando  `ip`:

```bsh
ip link show eth0 | awk '{print $9 }'
```

Primeiro, `ip link show eth0` mostra somente a interface de rede que você quer:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:01:1e:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Em seguida o *pipe* (o caractere `|`) pega esta saída e passa para o comando seguinte,  que no caso é o `awk`.

O `awk` separa o conteúdo de cada linha em campos, por padrão separados por espaços. Sendo assim, o nono campo (`$9`) é o que contém a informação que você quer. Por isso `print $9` mostra:

```
UP
```

---

Só que o comando acima também mostra uma linha em branco abaixo do `UP`, já que a segunda linha não tem 9 campos (se separarmos por espaços, são somente quatro), e por isso o `print $9` não imprime nada (mas o `print` por padrão coloca uma quebra de linha no final, então o resultado é uma linha em branco).

Uma alternativa para evitar esta linha em branco é usar [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) para pegar somente as linhas que possuem `eth0` e depois fazer o `awk` com esta linha:

```bsh
ip link show eth0 | grep eth0 | awk '{print $9 }'
```

Com isso ele só imprime `UP`, e não imprime a segunda linha em branco.

Outra alternativa é usar [`head`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/head) com a opção `-n 1` para trazer somente a primeira linha (a que tem `eth0`), assim não preciso do `grep`:

```bsh
ip link show eth0 | head -n 1 | awk '{print $9 }'
```

---

Se quer mesmo usar regex, você pode usar `grep` com a opção `-P` (que habilita a sintaxe *Perl Compatible* - já que por padrão o bash não suporta *lookbehind*):

```bsh
ip link show eth0 | head -n 1 | grep -o -P "(?<=state )\w+"
```

Isso também imprime `UP`.

Ou, se você tiver o Perl instalado:

```bsh
ip link show eth0 | head -n 1 | perl -ne 'print $1 if /eth0.*?state (\w+)/'
```

No caso, usei os parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) em torno do que eu quero: o `\w+` logo depois de "state". Assim, este grupo estará disponível na variável especial `$1` (já que é o primeiro grupo de captura). Esse código também imprime `UP`, mas sem a quebra de linha no final. Se quiser a quebra de linha, basta trocar por:

```bsh
ip link show eth0 | head -n 1 | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /eth0.*?state (\w+)/'
```

---

Mas ainda acho a solução com `awk` mais simples.

Comment: Não, não precisa ser regex. Eu acabei de testa este código, retornou UP como disse, mas o que é "awk"?

Comment: @MatheusLeite Atualizei a resposta com uma explicação

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente, obrigado!